npm install fails with ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
I'm facing an issue when trying to run npm install on my server. Here's the error message I'm receiving.
root@vmi1766336:/www/wwwroot/coinspay.xyz# npm install
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 7.14.0 -> 10.8.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.8.2 to update!
npm notice 
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmmirror.com/acorn-import-assertions/-/acorn-import-assertions-1.8.0.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www/server/nodejs/v14.4.0/cache/_logs/2024-07-23T14_29_48_739Z-debug.log
root@vmi1766336:/www/wwwroot/coinspay.xyz# 

please help me troubleshoot this request to https://registry.npmmirror.com/acorn-import-assertions/-/acorn-import-assertions-1.8.0.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4
Node: v14.4.0
NPM: 7.14.0
Thanks.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled Node + NPM and cleared npm cache.

Try to do a curl on "https://registry.npmmirror.com/acorn-import-assertions/-/acorn-import-assertions-1.8.0.tgz". Does your server can create outbound connections?

This issue might be due to a socket timeout issue faced in earlier versions of NPM, I would try updating to a version above 8.5.1 at least.

Thank you for your suggestion. I'm unable to upgrade to a newer version of Node.js and npm at the moment because my application requires the specific versions that are currently installed (Node.js v14.4.0 and npm v7.14.0) to function correctly. @DanielWasserlauf
